# Zabbix scheduled reports configuration - Cannot connect to web service: couldn't connect to server

Tags: zabbix

I recently upgraded Zabbix to 5.4.1 and I wanted to start using scheduled report, but I've got some problems with conifguration (error `Cannot connect to web service: couldn't connect to server`).

My Zabbix is running in Docker on Debian Buster. Everything is based on official containers:
Zabbix Server (PostgreSQL), Zabbix Frontend (Apache, PostreSQL) and PostgreSQL12.

According do documentation (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/install/web_service) I installed Google Chrome browser:

- wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
- sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

and Zabbix Web Service

- wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/debian/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_5.4-1+debian10_all.deb
- dpkg -i zabbix-release_5.4-1+debian10_all.deb
- apt install zabbix-web-service

I eddited zabbix_web_service.conf:
`AllowedIP=127.0.0.1,::1,0.0.0.0/0,zabbix`

I edited zabbix_server.conf: 
`StartReportWriters=1` 
`WebServiceURL=http://localhost:10053/report`

I eddited settings in Zabbix Frontend - Administration -> General -> Other 
`Frontend URL: http://localhost:8085` (frontend is available at port 8085)

But when I try to test report generating i get error:
`Cannot connect to web service: couldn't connect to server`

I've already tried with other Frontend URLs, but nothings seems to work. I tried with:
http://localhost:10053/report
http://192.168.10.18:8085/
http://192.168.10.18:10053/report

I've verified that I get answear from http://192.168.10.18:10053/report :
`{"detail":"Method is not supported."}`

What else can I check/try?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In server configuration I was usinng address http://localhost:10053/report it was wrong because in my case Zabbix server is running in docker and Zabbix web service is not running in docker. Zabbix server wasn't albe to connect to web servcie because it was in the other network. I changed the configuration and now everything works fine. Reports are beeing generated and send

Answer (score 0):

If you used docker complex to launch the application, first check if the zabbix-server and the zabbix web service are on the same docker network. If so, the WebServiceURL will not be **"http://localhost:10053/report"** but **"http:/zabbix-web-service:10053/report."**